# Store two values in HashMap value

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I want to store two values in hashMap's value field.

For example:

```
Key = 100, Value = 10, 20
```

I want to store in a way so that I could modify hashMap `Value` value using key ?

Lets say If I want to modify 10 to 30 then entry in map would be

```
Key = 100, Value = 30, 20
```

Any way so that I could control both `Value` values independently using key of hashmap ..?

Comment: `put` returns the old value, so ` new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1)` will evaluate to `(Integer)null`, as there is no previous value mapped to `"A"`. Generally, you should rethink your coding style.

Comment: note from moderator: do not change your question completely, as it invalidates existing answers. Instead, post a new question, linking to that one if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [com.google.common.collect.Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Example:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put(100, 10);
map.put(100, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> dualValueMap = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>();
    s1.add(10);
    s1.add(20);
    dualValueMap.put(100, s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also advocate using `#computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(100, k -> new ArrayList<>());
values.add(10);
values.add(20);
//100 -> [10, 20]
```

You can abstract the #computeIfAbsent call behind a method to ensure you always have a valid list value.